# Is it right to submit a conference abstract knowing that I will not attend but my advisor will give my talk instead?

Tags: ethics, conference, abstract

My postdoc finished 9 months ago. My former supervisor has asked me to submit an abstract on my work to a conference next year.

No-one intends that I will attend the conference. My ex-supervisor has an invited talk there, and basically wants current and former group members to also submit contributed talks that  can also be presented  if the main authors don’t show up.

The supervisor essentially wants to be able to give three or four talks for the cost of one attendee.  I don’t really feel this is right. On the other hand I also want to remain on good terms with them, as they are a reference on my current job applications, and we are also still working on papers together.

Should I refuse to submit an abstract? Or just bite the bullet and write something?

Comment: *He essentially wants to be able to give three or four talks for the cost of one attendee.* - Does the conference allow this? If so, what's the problem?

Comment: If he says you can present if you attend, then I don't see any poor intent if you choose not to and he presents your work in your stead.

Comment: I do not think cost is the issue here. One does not pay to present.  One pays to attend.  Honesty is the issue.

Comment: There are no funds available for me to attend, so I could only present myself if I self fund. Which my old boss knows I can't afford.

Comment: Who are the authors? Just you? Or you and your advisor?

Comment: There are four authors. But the advisor is the only one of the  four still at that institution.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: "One does not pay to present." - some conferences see this differently. (They require one attendance fee per each/every two/every three presented papers.) Chairs of such conferences can usually be "convinced" that they do not want to be a roadblock for a group that does get so many on-topic works accepted at a time, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be acceptable if and only if it is clearly communicated in the submission that the former supervisor is the intended presenter.  Deliberately misrepresenting who will present at the conference is dishonest.  If in doubt, contact someone at the conference.

Comment: On most (CS) conferences I have been to, it seemed fully acceptable that the identity of the presenter was not known (to the session chair) until as late as the beginning of the session. At this point, I fail to see how there could be any "misrepresenting who will present", unless the OP's advisor personally claims he is someone else while talking in front of the audience.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is right: I have never seen any conference put a cap on the number of talks a speaker can give, and it's quite commonplace that the speaker is not the primary author.

Comment: I agree it is common, but that does not justify deliberate dishonesty.  I generally assume that if the primary author does not show up it is due to honest mistake.  For example, I once presented for someone who was having a baby during the conference.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Seems like there are some customs in the OP's field that I am not aware of: is submitting an abstract considered as a commitment from the primary author to present?

Comment: In my opinion, yes it is a commitment unless otherwise specified, because if you do not show up you have wasted the reviewers' and attendees' time.

Comment: I agree it isn't unusual for a co-author to present, but as @AnonymousPhysicist says, this is normally when the primary has had to pull out at short notice

Comment: @Bob What is the field and does the conference specifically ask that primary author should present unless they unexpectedly cannot make it after the abstract has been accepted?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The field is materials science. I don't know if the conference specifies. It looks like I will have to at least begin the online submission process to see if there is any further guidance.

Comment: @Bob Well if the conference specifies no rule, you can't break any! :)